# Removing part of a link address with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hello, this is my .htaccess file so far.

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    Options -Indexes

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My current URL is *category/show/music*

How to convert it to *category/music* using htaccess? I want to to remove the *show/*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can't you configure a default action on your controller in whatever framework you're using? That would be a simpler solution.

Comment: i have own mvc ، i dont use the framework .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the entire file, your url `category/show/music` is rewritten to `index.php?url=category/show/music`. The following rewrite would 'insert' show for the index page. It would however be more sensible to edit `index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1/show/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine on` line:

```
RewriteRule ^(category)/show/(.+?)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```